# Checking if all values are selected for a column in DAX

Tags: dax

I need to write a query in SSAS Tabular model where I have a table with a column AREA with some 17 values. I need to write a query where I check if all the values of the AREA column are selected then it should consider the value as "WORLDWIDE". How to do this in if condition? What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
NumOfSelected = 
var __TotalItem = countrows(DISTINCT(ALL(Sheet1[ID])))
var __currentSelected = countrows(VALUES(Sheet1[ID]))

return
IF(__TotalItem = __currentSelected, "WorldWidth", "CurrentChoice:" & CONVERT( __currentSelected, STRING))
```

[image]

[image]